# Can I statically link ws2_32.lib in windows? c++ MFC

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I'm trying to deploy a single .exe file with a GUI written in c++. Using microsoft visual studio.

I have created the GUI with MFC and I can get it to build statically by changing the build options to:

Platform Toolset - Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)
Use of MFC - Use MFC in a Static Library
Runtime Library - Multi-threaded (/MT)

This works fine and gives me a GUI that I can execute on Windows 7/XP from a single .exe file.

However, I need to add in socket support because the program contains an IRC client. Therefore I need to include the libraries:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
```

However when I do this it will no-longer compile with:
Runtime Library - Multi-threaded (/MT)
instead it requires:
Runtime Library - Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)

Which means it is no-longer a portable .exe

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer compile" ? If you get an error message then post it.

Comment: Also, you won't be able to use winsock 'statically', because it's a DLL. /MD and /MT only control the C runtime linkage. That doesn't mean the executable isn't portable ; the DLL is always included in Windows.

Comment: You cannot statically link *ws2_32.lib*, and that is not your issue either. For one, all supported versions of Windows ship with a Windows Sockets implementation. Your real issue is, that you are mixing the release and debug versions of the CRT. You need to fix your build configurations.

Comment: winsock exists in every "imprtant" version of windows (vista and so one), you don't even need to link it statically. plus, if you are already using boost, switch to boost.asio

Answer (score 0):

The Visual C++ compiler embeds a list of default libraries in each obj file it creates. During linking, these default library directives are processed and the libraries are implicitly added to the link step.

This means that if two obj files were compiled with different C-Runtime settings there will be multiple C-Runtime libs being included at link time, which will conflict.

Generally, the correct solution is to rebuild the sources with the same C-Runtime settings as code compiled with the expectation that it will be used with a particular runtime might fail if used against a different one.

However, you can simply force a resolution to the situation by adding the unwanted libraries to the "Ignore Specific Default Libraries" Linker setting for the project.

The trick is to know which actual libraries map to which settings.

The [MSDN Use Runtime Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.80).aspx) lists the various runtimes that can be selected, in your case, you want to exclude the static multithreaded debug runtime from being included in your build, so `libcmtd.lib` needs to be added to default libraries to ignore.